# What is correct "El fuego de mi espíritu" or "Fuego de mi espíritu"?

Tags: gramática

> Tierra es mi cuerpo. Agua mi sangre. Aire mi aliento. Fuego mi espiritu.

and

> Tierra mi cuerpo. Agua mi sangre. Aire mi aliento. El fuego de mi espíritu.

Wich one is more correct as a tatoo?

Answer (score 4):

La primera es la correcta.

The first one is better than the second because the last part in the second phrase: 'El fuego de mi espíritu' sounds weird in the context.

Sorry for my english... spanish is my main language

Comment: Puedes responder en español. De hecho, es preferido!